# boost::Thread without library windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, boost

I would like to avoid building a whole library for just `boost::Thread`. So I added the cpp files in libs/Thread to my project and it worked under GCC on MacOS.

However, Visual Studio on Windows tells me

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-s-1_47.lib'

This doesnt seem right to me since AFAIK I didnt add a library requirement to my project. Why does it want me to add that and how does boost do it without changing my project settings?

Or am I mistaken after all...

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to your pre-processor definitions will keep boost packages from "auto-linking" on Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much, that along with BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Boost uses `#pragma comment(lib, library_name)` to tell the compiler to link with specific libraries. If you don't want to use the code in a library with that name, you'll probably need to find the `#pragma` and delete (or change) it. Alternatively, you could use the `nodefaultlib` option with the linker.

Another way would be to use `bcp` to extract the part(s) of Boost you want, then build and use the libraries it creates.

Comment: Thanks, that explains how they did it :)