# Boost::Pool not linking

Tags: c++, boost, boost-pool

I am using `boost::pool`.  It only has header file, no dll or o or lib file. It should work without them.

When I compile my code though it says:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib'
```

Why is this? There should be no .lib that causes a problem.

Comment: boost pool depends on threads which is NOT header-only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost::Thread without library windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691184/boostthread-without-library-windows)

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about `Boost.Pool`, but the documentation *does* say that it is header-only. You are probably including `Boost.Threads` somewhere in your program, or some part of `Boost.Pool` relies on `Boost.Threads`.

I see you're using **MSVC**. You need to have the *Boost* libraries in you *library search path*; the method for adding search directories depends on the *version* of MSVC you're using.

If you haven't built the Boost library binaries yet, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010) for some tips.

Here's a good [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-from-within-the-visual-studio-ide) from Boost itself.

And [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe(v=vs.100).aspx) from Mircrosoft will show you how to set your library directory. Use the link/dropdown at the top of the page to get specific instructions for *your* version of MSVC.

Comment: Appreciate you time anthony. Thank you.